# Packaging node workspace as a .tgz file so that it can be installed via npm install

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-workspaces

I'm just getting started trying to use `node` and `npm` in a real project (well, kind-of real), and I'm very confused by how the "packaging" process works.

I have a directory called `wstest`:

```
{
  "name": "@foo/wstest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "workspaces": [
    "./packages/*"
  ]
}
```

In the mentioned "packages" subdirectory are two other directories, `plazadb-data` and `plazadb-bulk`. This is all just dummy code, but here's the top-level `index.js`:

```
const data = require("@foo/plazadb-data");
const bulk = require("@foo/plazadb-bulk");

console.log("Hello from workspace!");
```

In that directory, `node index.js` works.

After `npm install` from the top-level directory there, I get `node_modules` like this:

```
node_modules
  @foo
    plazadb-data
    plazadb-bulk
```

with the correct stuff in there.

Now, however, if I do `npm pack` in that directory, the `.tgz` file I get has the intervening `packages` subdirectory, and that's what I get in a separate test directory into which I `npm install` from the tarball:

```
node_modules
  @foo
    wstest
      packages
        plazadb-data
        plazadb-bulk
```

(The "wstest" is the name of the top-level source directory, where the `package.json` has the "workspaces" clause.) What that means is that `require()` statements in the original test directory *don't* work as they appear; I need to explicitly include the path, *including* the top-level directory from the test source tree:

```
const data = require("@foo/wstest/packages/plazadb-data");
const bulk = require("@foo/wstest/packages/plazadb-bulk");

console.log("Hello from workspace installation test!");
```

This does not seem like the way things are supposed to be. I've tried fiddling with the workspace-related options on `npm pack`, but that seems not to have any effect (not that I understand from the documentation what they're *supposed* to do).

All I want to do is:

- have a source tree with a couple of packages, managed as a single git repository with a single `npm` way of dealing with it all;
- create tarballs from the workspace for internal distribution and testing.

What I *don't* want is to publish this stuff anywhere; my organization does not have a Node infrastructure or really any significant expertise (probably obvious).

I'm sure I have some fundamental misunderstanding of how the tools are intended to work. I have no idea how to make make a tarball such that from a directory into which the tarball is installed, `require("@foo/plazadb-data")` does the right thing. Maybe you can't do that from a tarball at all; I don't know.

Oh, and the versions of everything involved are all very recent.

Comment: If you just want to pack one workspace, then `npm --workspace <which> pack`. Same as any other command to run in one workspace. Or you can `npm --workspaces pack` to put all of them in separate tarballs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. I barely understand the "workspace" thing, so I don't really know what that means. I don't even know if "pack" is the verb I'm looking for. I want the sub-packages to the workspace to end up as top-level directories under the scope name in the target directories where I install it (whatever "it" ends up being; I don't really care *what* it is.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe and no, I want to "package" (in any way that works) the collection of sub-packages in the workspace, all of them. `npm pack` does do that, but it does it in a way that I find surprising. Perhaps it's my expectations that are wrong.

Comment: You say "no", but then describe a thing I said how to do, so I'm a little confused. Maybe start by reading e.g. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces. If you `npm pack` _without_ specifying any or all workspaces it just packs everything from the root, like a non-workspace project, which is what you're doing but not what you want.

Comment: OK, so what you're saying is that I need to make *separate* tarballs for each package in the workspace? I can try that. However that seems like it takes a little of potential niceness out of the workspace; it'd be good if I could have just one thing to install elsewhere. Again, however, I may be very much confused about how things are intended to work.

Comment: Well the point of workspaces is that you can have separate packages within one project. Each package is one pack. If that's not what you want, e.g. you just want a single package with multiple modules inside, then maybe you don't want a workspace at all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yea the reason I started looking into workspaces is that I want to avoid too many ugly path navigation `require()` statements, and to kind-of flatten things out (Node people seem to really like flat hierarchies, unlike my old friends in the Java world). I may have made a wrong turn. Thank you for your help and advice, of course.